# solution paths LARS and LASSO

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

In “Model selection and estimation in regression with grouped variables (2005)” , the authors (Yuan and Lin) claim that “It is easy to see that this is identical to the solution path of group LARS when X is orthonormal”. The piecewise linear solution path of group lasso is identical to the path of group lars if the design matrix X is orthonormal on page 56.

But I don’t have any idea how to check that claim. Why are the solution paths of the group Least Angle Regression Selection and the group LASSO identical to each other?
Thanks!

Comment: We can see if you get a helpful response here, but I'm guessing our [Crosvalidated site](https://stats.stackexchange.com) may be a better fit for this question.